# [quicksearch] How to determine number of displayed rows?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, quick-search

I'm using jQuery with TableSorter and QuickSearch plugins.  These work fine.

How can I:

1. dynamically display row numbers for each displayed row?
2. somewhere on my page, display the total number of displayed rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $('tr:visible').length
```

Will you give the number of visible rows on the page.

Something along the lines of:

```
 var rowCount = $('tr:visible').length;
 $('#rowCountDiv').html(rowCount + "rows");
```

Will write out the number into a div on your page with an id of `rowCountDiv`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the proper answer.  In the PHP use something like this:

```
echo "Dynamic count: <p id=\"count\"></p>";
```

Then in the quickSearch add an onAfter function.

```
onAfter: function() {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=($('tr:visible').length-1);
}
```

Voila!  Now you have a dynamic count that updates whenever the table is searched.