# How do I get the rowNum programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

By rowNum I mean the number showed on the picture below.
I tried  to get it like `$('#gridId').rowNum` but it gave me undefined. I understand that I can get it like any other html element value using jQuery, my question is does jqGrid provide any API to do that?

[image]

**UPDATE:** Version of jqGrid is 4.4.4

**UPDATE 2:** This question is correctly answered in the comment. Now there is another issue which has to do with this topic ([Trouble with getting rowNum inside the function that handles onPaging event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342989/trouble-with-getting-rownum-inside-the-function-that-handles-onpaging-event)).

Comment: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461814/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-rows-displayed-in-a-jqgrid) seems to think you can use `jqGrid.getGridParam('rowNum');`

Answer (score 0):

.selectedIndex is the property you want for a select.

```
document.getElementById("gridId").options[document.getElementById("gridId").selectedIndex].innerHTML;

$('#gridId').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#gridId").val()
```

Or, if you need the text (not the value):

```
$("#gridId option:selected").text();
```