# Trouble with getting rowNum inside the function that handles onPaging event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I change the rowNum in paging combobox (see below)
[image]

I want to find out which number was selected so I have decided to use the next approach:

```
onPaging : function(pgButton) {
  onPagingHandler(pgButton);
}
```

...

```
function onPagingHandler(pgButton) {
  if (pgButton != "records"){
    return;
  }
  alert($("#gridId").getGridParam('rowNum'));
}
```

The issue is when I got say **10** selected in the combobox and now I am selecting say **30**, inside the event handler this code `$("#gridId").getGridParam('rowNum')` still give me previous value (which is **10**). Why doesn't it give me **30** and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value directly from the select:

```
onPaging : function(pgButton) {
    if (pgButton != "records"){
        return;
    }

    var newRowNum = $(".ui-pg-selbox", this.p.pager).val();
}
```

Comment: this.p.pager didn't work for me so I had to use only this.p and it worked good for me

Comment: @AntonKasyanchuk: Probably you used `this.p.pager` inside of `onPagingHandler` instead of direct usage it in `onPaging`. The code `onPaging: function (pgButton) { onPagingHandler(pgButton); }` don't forward `this` initialized to DOM of grid `$("#gridId")[0]`. You should either use `onPaging: onPagingHandler` or `onPaging: function (pgButton) { onPagingHandler.call(this, pgButton); }`